# How to write a javascript for reloading a page in the same tab after every t seconds?

Tags: javascript

I am javascript newbie. I need to collect the packet traces for a webpage by reloading it in the same tab every 30 seconds. How can I do this using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a HTML only solution:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.html">
```

Or use Javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 30000);
```

Both ways refresh the current page every 30 seconds. Right from MDC:

> Reload the document from the current
>   URL. forceget is a boolean, which,
>   when it is true, causes the page to
>   always be reloaded from the server. If
>   it is false or not specified, the
>   browser may reload the page from its
>   cache.

Comment: How can I open the page on a new tab?

Comment: @Bruce: to open an address in a new tab/window you need to invoke `window.open()` (see docs). Whether the url is opened in a new tab or window is decided by the browser (user settings most time)